# PyQt5: QSqlRelationalTableModel populate data with SqlAlchemy Model?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyqt5, qtableview

I am trying to subclass `QSqlRelationalTableModel` to work with SQLAlchemy, I am having trouble setting the data.

I am looking to override the [setData method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlrelationaltablemodel.html#setData), however, I am not sure how to do that.  so far my class looks like:

```
import sys
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.orm import class_mapper

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlTableModel, QSqlRelationalTableModel
from PyQt5.Qt import QVariant, Qt

base = declarative_base()

class SqlAlchemyTableRelationalModel(QSqlRelationalTableModel):
    def __init__(self, session, model):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = model
        self.session = session
        self.refresh()

    def refresh(self):
        self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
        self.data = self.session.query(self.model).all()
        self.count = len(self.data)
        self.columns = attribute_names(self.model)
        self.layoutChanged.emit()

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        '''Overrides QSqlTableModel rowCount
        '''
        return self.count or 0

    def setTable(self):
        return self.model.__tablename__
```

For example if I test with a simple `User` class,

```
class User(base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String(50))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<User(id={self.id}, name={self.name})>"
```

with some test data,

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    engine = sa.create_engine("sqlite:///my_db.db", echo='debug')
    base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    DBsession = sa.orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = DBsession()

    # pop some dummy data
    if not session.query(User).count():
        session.add(User(name="Albert"))
        session.add(User(name="Frankie"))
        session.add(User(name="Grace"))
        session.commit()

    model = SqlAlchemyTableRelationalModel(session, User)


    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    table = QtWidgets.QTableView(window)
    table.setModel(model)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I get,

[image: currently looks like]

Comment: Why QSqlRelationalTableModel and not QSqlTableModel?

Comment: Well the docs for QSqlRelationalTableModel are `The QSqlRelationalTableModel class provides an editable data model for a single database table, with foreign key support.` for the model I posted there is no FK, however, it is a simple case. I am still in the "hello world" part where I am just trying to get it up and running.  Eventually, I will have models with FK's.

Comment: In your "Hello World" status I recommend you first try the basics like implementing a *QSqlQueryModel* based on SQLAlchemy, and then just try a *QSqlTableModel*, *QSqlRelationalTableModel* based on SQLAlchemy.

Comment: The above I point out because you seem not to understand how the models work, QSqlXXXModel is based on QtSql, and have a structure that internally make the queries, so you understand I recommend you check the source code: http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/sql/models?h=dev

Comment: Your starting point should be a class that inherits from QAbstractTableModel where you implement queries based on SQLAlchemy, and not QSqlXXXModel. QSqlRelationalTableModel inherits from QSqlTableModel, so internally you will make the queries with QtSql even though you have placed that code.

Comment: I recommend you check the following example: https://gist.github.com/harvimt/4699169, since you are going the wrong way, you want to build a boat using a plane as a base.

Comment: In conclusion, implement the basics as a SqlQueryModel based on QAbstractTableModel using SQLAlchemy, after understanding the logic you can think of implementing more complex models such as QSqlTableModel and QSqlRelationalTableModel.